# Send audio .mp3/.wav files to Chrome microphone

Tags: google-chrome, audio, microphone

I am using a web page which has a microphone incorporated, same like "Search by voice" feature of Google search.

In Developers tools -> Network I see that a .wav file is created which is sent to the engine for processing.

dev tools -> network:

[image: dev tools -> network]

Is there any way to manually send .wav files to Chrome for processing?(simulating audio recording)